# Age of universe and its relativistic effect

Tags: universe, relativity

Can anybody explain the age of universe in conjunction with Einstein's theory of relativity?
Is it possible that this calculation is relative to earth and would be different if some other intelligent being calculated it, which is living close to a black hole or a giant star?